# In my Node app, request params come back as expected outside of a Docker container but are read as undefined inside of one. What's happening?

Tags: node.js, docker, express, request

I wrote a Node/Express service that acts as a middleman between its client and another service. It reads REST request parameters from the client and puts them into a SOAP request to pass to the next service, then writes the response to a database.

In the original, non-Dockerized version of the app running locally on my machine, it can read the values of the request params from the client without issue; however, once it was Dockerized and I ran it in a container locally, the request param values started coming back as "undefined." Does anyone know why this would happen and what a possible solution could be? Thanks in advance.

Example of what I'm trying to do (a bit contrived to protect company code but gets the point across):

```
let orderId = req.body.orderId;

console.log(orderId); // read without issue outside of Docker but says undefined in Docker

let soapReq = soapHelper.createReq(orderId);

let svcResponse = soapHelper.sendReq(soapReq);

res.send(svcResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you expose the necessary ports when running the Docker Container?

`docker run -p 8080:8080 container:tag`

Comment: Hi, Julian. I believe it is exposed correctly... The container is running just fine and all other app functions besides reading the req params seem to be working. It's very odd!